# ROS How to pass a callback variable into another file?

Tags: python, ros

I have a callback function in a file "color.py" that constantly recieves incoming data but updates a global variable every 3 seconds:

```
last_color = ""
last_calltime = datetime.strptime("00:00:00","%H:%M:%S")

def callback(data):
   global last_calltime, last_color
   cube = data.data
   t = time.localtime()
   tf = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S",t)
   current_time = datetime.strptime(tf, "%H:%M:%S")
   delta_time = current_time - last_calltime

if abs(delta_time.total_seconds()) >= 3:
    if "Red" in cube:
        last_color = "Red"
    elif "Green" in cube:
        last_color = "Green"
    else:
        last_color = "Blue"

    t = time.localtime()
    tf = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S",t)
    last_calltime = datetime.strptime(tf, "%H:%M:%S")

    return last_color



if __name__ == '__main__':

try:
    rospy.init_node('color')
    rospy.Subscriber ('/topic',String, callback)
    rospy.spin()
```

In another file, I need to reference this "last_color" variable that updates. So far the function I have in this file:

```
from color import last_color
    
    a = 0

    def observe_color(a)
       if a == 0:
         return last_color 
       else: 
         return "None"
```

I need this to return the updated variable from the "color.py" file but it only returns the initialized value for last_color which is "". How can I do this?

Comment: This is all being done inside ros. Why does the other file not just have a subscriber?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's gonna work that way. How about save the value of `last_color` to a file and monitor it ? Because to me you run 2 separated programs, 1 with the ROS and another just to monitor `last_color`

```
while True:
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        color = f.readline()
    time.sleep(timesteps)
```

When write to file in the `main`, you could also append the read value and also the time, to get timeline data.

Comment: Will this work even if last_color is constantly updating? How can save the value of this variable to a new file and monitor it, what would the code look like? Thank you!

Comment: you would need a loop to read the file again every timestep (1 sec, 2 sec, etc)

Comment: Sockets are almost always a better option for inter-process comms. Also it's probably not super important for OPs use case but it should be noted that this solution does technically run the risk of grabbing stale/incorrect data from the subscriber.

Answer (score 0):

When you import something in Python, you're effectively asking it to execute everything in that module in the same runtime as your current program.

Suppose I have some module `color.py` with variable `last_color='green'`

And in a different program `observer.py` I have `from color import last_color`

The `last_color` that exists in `color.py` and the `last_color` that exists in `observer.py` are different places in computer memory - they do not reference the same string value.

A quick (and maybe dirty) solution to this is just to re-import the module every time you want to observe one of its member variables.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is all done in ROS it would be easiest to simply have the separate file initialize as a ros node with a subscriber. If for some reason that's not the case you should make `color.py` a class and have the other file initialize  an object. Take the following simplified example:

**color.py**

```
class colorPy:
    def __init__(self):
        self.last_color = None
        rospy.init_node('some_node')
        tmp = rospy.Subscriber('/some_topic', self.callback)
    def callback(self, msg):
        self.last_color = msg.data
```

**other file**

```
from color import colorPy
from time import sleep
local_var = colorPy()
sleep(5)
print(local_var.last_color)
```